# Hive job over DynamoDB doesn't progress

Tags: hive, amazon-dynamodb

I've got about 35GB (22 million rows) of web click data in a DynamoDB database. I can pull data by keys just fine. I'm trying now to use Hive to computate aggregations on that data, and am having trouble getting even basic things to work.

My DynamoDB is set up with a read throughput of 40. My EMR is set up with an m1.small master and three m1.large cores. I'm doing the following in Hive:

```
SET dynamodb.throughput.read.percent=1.0;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AntebellumHive (user_id string, session_time string, page_count string, custom_os string)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' 
TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "AntebellumClickstream", 
"dynamodb.column.mapping" = "user_id:user_id,session_time:session_time,page_count:x-page-count,custom_os:x-custom-os"); 

select count(*)
from AntebellumHive
WHERE session_time > "2012/08/14 11:48:00.210 -0400"
  AND session_time < "2012/08/14 12:48:00.210 -0400";
```

So, I'm mapping four columns (including the user_id key and the session_time range field, and two other things). Then I'm just trying to count the number of rows in an hour's worth of data, which should be on the order of hundreds.

Here's the output:

```
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
Starting Job = job_201212031719_0002, Tracking URL = http://ip-xxxxx.ec2.internal:9100/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201212031719_0002
Kill Command = /home/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -Dmapred.job.tracker=x.x.x.x:9001 -kill job_201212031719_0002
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
2012-12-03 19:13:58,988 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2012-12-03 19:14:59,415 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4.5 sec
2012-12-03 19:15:00,423 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4.5 sec
2012-12-03 19:15:01,435 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4.5 sec
2012-12-03 19:15:02,441 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4.5 sec
2012-12-03 19:15:04,227 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4.5 sec
2012-12-03 19:15:05,233 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4.5 sec
2012-12-03 19:15:06,255 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4.5 sec
2012-12-03 19:15:07,263 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4.5 sec
2012-12-03 19:15:08,269 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4.5 sec
2012-12-03 19:15:09,275 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4.5 sec
2012-12-03 19:15:10,290 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4.5 sec
2012-12-03 19:15:11,296 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 4.5 sec
```

(masked IPs.) Every minute or so, I get another second of CPU time, but the map% never increases from zero, even after 20 minutes or longer, and it never completes. I can definitely see stuff happening in the monitoring graphs for both Dynamo and EMR.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If I am reading your post correctly you have 35 GB of data and you are trying to read the data using 40 read IOPS.
40 IOPS roughly translate to 40 KBPS for a scan. This means that it will approximately take 254 hours to complete the query.

Hive updates the query percentage once one or more mappers finish processing. Since each mapper created is potentially going to take a very long time to run you will not see Hive update soon.

You can log on to Hadoop UI on the master node and see the Hadoop statistics. It will show you the individual map task status and some statistics around data read. Please refer to the doc:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-web-interfaces.html
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingtheHadoopUserInterface.html

Comment: Ah, thanks. This is the type of information that wasn't present in the DynamoDB documentation, even about backups. So should I expect to crank my IOPS up to 4000 or so to export this data? Is there some best-practices documentation about this that I've not yet found?